# jQuery Binary Clock

Tags: javascript, jquery

I haven't worked with jQuery or Javascript really. Could someone please tell me how I would go about implementing this [Binary Clock](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/binaryClock)?

Comment: Even just a resource? I'm just not sure how to call a function from a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the following URL:

http://www.scottklarr.com/files/binary-clock/clock.htm

and view the source.

**Here is a breakdown:**

This code sets up jQuery and the plugin:

```
<head>
<link href="binary-clock.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="binary-clock.js"></script>
</head>
```

It also references a style sheet, which can be downloaded from http://www.scottklarr.com/files/binary-clock/clock.css

This code:

```
<div id="binaryClock">
    <div id="bcHa">
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcHa1" />
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcHa2" />
    </div>
    <div id="bcHb" class="edge">
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcHb1" />
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcHb2" />
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcHb4" />
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcHb8" />
    </div>

    <div id="bcMa">
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcMa1" />
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcMa2" />
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcMa4" />
    </div>
    <div id="bcMb" class="edge">
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcMb1" />
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcMb2" />
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcMb4" />
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcMb8" />
    </div>

    <div id="bcSa">
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcSa1" />
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcSa2" />
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcSa4" />
    </div>
    <div id="bcSb">
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcSb1" />
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcSb2" />
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcSb4" />
        <img src="led0.png" alt="" id="bcSb8" />
    </div>
</div>
```

...is where the actual clock is referenced on the page.  It contains div references for all of the image files that comprise the dot elements of the clock.  It also contains some CSS class references, so some styling is taking place.

This code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
         updateBinaryClock(); 
    });
</script>
```

...waits for the page to fully load in the browser, and then kickstarts the clock plugin.

Comment: $this.append('<div class="clock"><d... 
Does that code mean that it needs no container? It just writes directly to the html file?

I have a <script> in the head the src's the file.

And this:
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() { binaryClock(); });</script>
in the body. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: If you save a copy of the page source at the link above as an .HTM file into a folder on your computer, and put the scripts and images being used by that web page in the same folder, it should just work.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I legitimately want to learn what I'm doing. Thanks for the help though. I think I'm getting close.

Comment: To be precise, this is clock expresses the current time in [binary-coded decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) values and is therefore not truly binary.

Binary-coded decimal clocks are though the most common "binary" clocks.

Comment: @scniro: http://matt-nicholson.com/clock/binary-clock.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey awesome thank you!

Comment: still pretty table based, but I took the basis of that example and recreated something slightly more straightforward and can be found in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wc0ubojs/). It's pretty untested, so please reply in this thread if anything seems wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Use this JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#clock_div').binaryClock();
});
```

For this HTML code:

```
<div id="clock_div"></div>
```

Demo (with plugin source) [here](http://webdesk.homelinux.org/clock.html).